# how to use OnPause method

Tags: android

How to change button text loaded from EditText while in onPause() method?

For example

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    button.setText(text.getText().toString());
    super.onPause()
}
```

When I press the back button it does not change the button text

Comment: So you want to retain the value in the textbox when the user returns to that activity?

Comment: What is your issue? Could not understand nothing

Comment: why you want do somethin like that

Comment: no i want to change  the text of the button as text loaded from the edittext and this text which is loaded from the edit text keep to the button permanently i mean the text which is loaded from the edit text  to the button so the button has this text permanently .

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the question of why you want to do this in `onPause()` in the first place...

Normally, the state of your views would be saved in `onSaveInstanceState(...)`.  But according to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), there are no guarantees about whether the call to `onSaveInstanceState(...)` will occur before or after the call to `onPause()`.  If `onSaveInstanceState(...)` is called before `onPause()`, then any changes you make in `onPause()` will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) - it describes Android activity flow with excellent diagrams.
onPause() is already existing method in Your activity, thus You will need to `@Override` it. Unless You modified back button behavior - here is what happens:

- onPause() is executed when You press back, and button text is replaced (assuming text and button are visible in this scope) - for such short time, You won't be able to notice (unless device is lagging, anyway)
- onStop() is executed next, and Your application exits shortly after

If You want to try and check that text is properly set - You might find it easier to write:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Text's text:" + text.getText().toString()
          + "Button:" + button.getText().toString());

}
```

You will need to import `android.util.Log`.
Notice also, that it is highly recommended ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)) that You call super() as first thing when overriding Android default methods.

Comment: sir i added the code as you mentioned but when i press the back button show unfortunately app has stoped worked